# Populate Android listview via c# web service

Tags: android, web-services

I have a poor English so I apologise if I do spelling mistakes.

I have a web service that written in C# and I want to make an application of Android which listview populated by the web service. Also the application must listen any changing data and re populate listview immediately. And last thing is that if any timer runs on the phone like call etc. also my application should continue to work properly.

I am new on Android, so I need your help. Where should I start and where can I find docs for my aim. Thx so much

Comment: what type of Server API? REST? if so check Retrofit. To notify server changes look on FCM (old GCM)

Comment: My web service uses SOAP protocol